# Pulling top 10% of data pandas python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, function, methods, filter

I am currently working on a code

```py
VRAM1[VRAM1["System"] == "AIS V1"].plot(kind='scatter', x='ReportDate', y='Site',figsize = (15,120));
plt.title('AIS V1 System')
```

My output is exactly what I want to see.  The frustrating part is how do I see the top 10% of the AIS V1 scatter plot. Currently I see ALL (y='Site'), but I only want to see the top 10% and not all.  The AIS V1 data are objects and not integers so I was not able to use the nlargest() function. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: top 10% base on `Site` ?

Comment: It will be the top 10% on AIS V1. the scatter plot graph shows the how often AIS V1 will show up, 'Site' are names and want to know how often does AIS V1 shows up over time "ReportDate",  Does that help?

Comment: Basically, you can sort the data using `DataFrame.sort_values()` function and then slice to get top 10%. It could be better if you share some of the data you are dealing with.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to share the data.  I think I was able to find what I needed, thank you for your time and help Hoai!

Comment: If you solved it please consider writing an answer detailing your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
VRAM1[VRAM1["System"] == "AIS V1"].head(int(len(VRAM1)*0.1)).plot(kind='scatter', x='ReportDate', y='Site',figsize = (15,120));
plt.title('AIS V1 System')
```